# Use concurrent futures with dictionary.items() to iterate through key, values

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, concurrent.futures

I want to scrape data from webpage in more efficient way. I read about concurrent futures but I have no idea how to use it in my script.

My function to take data from each link takes four arguments:

`def scrape_data_for_offer(b, m, url, loc):`

then it saves **scraped** data do pandas date frame.

It's called in a loop:

```
for link, location in cars_link_dict.items():
    scrape_data_for_offer(brand, model, link, location)
```

and I want it to speed up this **scraping** process.

I tried to solve it like this:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
    executor.map(scrape_data_for_offer, brand, model, cars_link_dict.items())
```

But it doesn't work, do you have any ideas of how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your futures case, you're only passing three items.  The last item is a two-element tuple.  So, change your function to:

```
    def scrape_data_for_offer(b,m,info):
        url, loc = info
```

By the way, the words are "scrape", "scraped" and "scraping".  Many, many, many people are using "scr*p", "scr*pped" and "scr*pping", but those words all refer to throwing things away.

As another by the way, the concurrent stuff is not really going to help you.  I assume you are using BeautifulSoup for the scraping.  BeautifulSoup is all Python code, and the global interpreter lock means that only one of the threads will be able to execute at any given time.  You'll get a tiny bit of overlap while waiting for the web site responses to be delivered.

Also, running 50 workers is pointless unless you have 50 processors.  They'll all fight for resources.  If you have 8 processors, use about 12 workers.  In most cases, you should just leave off that parameter; it will default to the number of processors in your machine.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! Do you think there is a way to speed up this process? I have to take date from about 200,000 auctions. It's for my university project, after downloading this data I will work with it using pandas library.

Comment: Not significantly.  You will gain a bit with concurrent, because the first page will be able to start processing while the second and third pages are still waiting for the network, but fetching 200,000 web pages is going to take a long time.  I suspect you are I/O bound rather than compute bound.